# An optimized stored procedure to replace this LINQ statement

Tags: sql-server, database, stored-procedures, c#-4.0, linq-to-entities

I have the following two tables in SQL Server 2008

```
TABLE [JobUnit](
    [idJobUnit] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Job_idJob] [int] NOT NULL,  // Foreign key here
    [UnitStatus] [tinyint] NOT NULL, // can be (0 for unprocessed, 1 for processing, 2 for processed)   
    )

TABLE [Job](
    [idJob] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [JobName] [varchar(50)] NOT NULL,   
    )
```

Job : JobUnit is one-to-many relationship

I am trying to write an efficient store procedure that would replace the following LINQ statement

```
public enum UnitStatus{
    unprocessed,
    processing,
    processed,
}

int jobId = 10;

using(EntityFramework context = new EntityFramework())
{
    if (context.JobUnits.Where(ju => ju.Job_idJob == jobId)
        .Any(ju => ju.UnitStatus == (byte)UnitStatus.unproccessed))
    {
        // Some JobUnit is unprocessed
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        // There is no unprocessed JobUnit
        if (context.JobUnits.Where(ju => ju.Job_idJob == jobId) //
            .Any(ju => ju.UnitStatus == (byte)UnitStatus.processing))
        {                   
            // JobUnit has some unit that is processing, but none is unprocessed 
            return 2;
        }
        else
        {
            // Every JoUnit is processed
            return 3;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for reading

Comment: what is wrong with the LINQ approach?

Comment: @KIvanov: I'm guessing that the OP wants better performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So really, you're just looking for the lowest state of all the units in a particular job?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetJobState @jobId int AS
SELECT MIN(UnitStatus)
FROM JobUnit 
WHERE Job_idJob = @jobId
```

I should also say you could use this approach just as easly in Linq.

Comment: The behavior is different compared to the sample if there is no job with the given `@jobId`. You may want to use something like `SELECT COALESCE(MIN(UnitStatus+1), 3)` instead.

Comment: /Facepalm You are absolutely right, how could I miss that.  I am blind :(